# Possible to target multiple namespaces?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

Let's say I have the following XML:

```
<Data xmlns:R="Rows" xmlns:C="Columns" xmlns:V="Values">
    <R:ProductGroup value="Electronics">
        <R:Product value="Computer">
            <C:Year value="2018">
                <V:SumOfRevenue value="104" />
                <V:SumOfUnits value="3" />
            </C:Year>
            <C:Year value="2019">
                <V:SumOfRevenue value="82" />
                <V:SumOfUnits value="9" />
            </C:Year>
            <C:Year value="(all)">
                <V:SumOfRevenue value="186" />
                <V:SumOfUnits value="12" />
            </C:Year>
        </R:Product>
    </R:ProductGroup>
</Data>
```

The data is separated into `Rows` and `Columns`. And so I can target a Row Element by doing something like `//R:Name` and a column with `//C:Name`. Is it possible to use a third namespace (or whatever it would be called) to target **both**. For example, something like `A:` (standing for "All") that could target either a column or a row? Or, is it even possible to 'skip' the namespace evaluation (perhaps something like `local-name(...)`) to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you using any language or database? Or just pure XPath?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky just XPath (1.0)

Comment: In such case the only solution is what Alexandra Dudkina suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible using `local-name()` function. Here is an example of XPath expression which will return value "9":

```
//*[local-name()='Product'][@value='Computer']/*[local-name()='Year'][@value='2019']/*[local-name()='SumOfUnits']/@value
```